# MongoDB- How to show the period with most number of an occurence?

Tags: mongodb, date, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to MongoDB so I am having issues with finding the period with the most number of occurrences.

I have a collection with documents pertaining to different countries and `date_start` and `date_end`.

```json
"country": "Austria",
    "date_start": "2020-03-16",
    "date_end": "2020-05-04"
```

I want to find the time period in which most countries overlap (this collection details the periods a country has a certain event). For example:

```
1 ------------------------------------------------ 2



        3ooooooooooooooooooooooooo4
        


5~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~6
```

I wish to obtain the period whereby the most countries overlap, which is in this example between 3 and 6.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure about your explanation.
This is a result of a **Country** with the most countries overlapping by the date range.

Aggregation with **INNER JOIN**($lookup), filtering($filter) the dates between the range of the primary country by projecting($project) values from results:

*last aggregation operation sets which fields from the original collection are $project-ed.*

**Aggregation example**:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      pipeline: [],
      "as": "countries"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "country": 1,
      "date_start": 1,
      "date_end": 1,
      "in_date_range": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$countries",
          as: "item",
          cond: {
            "$and": [
              {
                "$ne": [
                  "$$item.country",
                  "$country"
                ]
              },
              {
                "$lt": [
                  "$$item.date_start",
                  "$date_end"
                ]
              },
              {
                "$gte": [
                  "$$item.date_end",
                  "$date_start"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "country": 1,
      "date_start": 1,
      "date_end": 1,
      "in_date_range": {
        "$map": {
          input: "$in_date_range.country",
          as: "country",
          in: "$$country"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Mongo playground example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/DpUo694EEl9

More on aggregation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/